# JDBC CallableStatement: java.sql.SQLException: The user specified as a definer ('mysql.infoschema'@'localhost') does not exist

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I just started to contact the JDBC and I met some problem about CallableStatement, here is my code:

```
    Connection connection=null;
    CallableStatement statement=null;

    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DBTools.getDbUrl(), DBTools.getUSER(),DBTools.getPASSWD());
        String getNameSQL="{call getName (?,?)}";
        statement=connection.prepareCall(getNameSQL);
        int empID=103;
        String empName;
        statement.setInt(1,empID);
        statement.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
        System.out.println("Execute: "+statement.execute());
        empName=statement.getString(2);
        System.out.println("Emp Name with ID:" + empID + " is " + empName);
        statement.close();
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Its console output is:

```
java.sql.SQLException: The user specified as a definer ('mysql.infoschema'@'localhost') does not exist
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:970)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1020)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.DatabaseMetaDataUsingInfoSchema.executeMetadataQuery(DatabaseMetaDataUsingInfoSchema.java:70)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.DatabaseMetaDataUsingInfoSchema.getProcedureColumns(DatabaseMetaDataUsingInfoSchema.java:769)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.CallableStatement.determineParameterTypes(CallableStatement.java:790)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.CallableStatement.<init>(CallableStatement.java:585)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.CallableStatement.getInstance(CallableStatement.java:484)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.parseCallableStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:1523)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareCall(ConnectionImpl.java:1548)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareCall(ConnectionImpl.java:1539)
at main.JDBCCallableStatement.main(JDBCCallableStatement.java:13)
```

The line 13 is: statement=connection.prepareCall(getNameSQL);

I'm sure that the mysql function getName() was created and works well, it seems that the problem is Connection, but I don't know how to fix it, hope you can give me some suggestions.

Comment: By the way,  the code <connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DBTools.getDbUrl(), DBTools.getUSER(),DBTools.getPASSWD()); > works well in my other project using Statement and PreparedStatement, maybe the way of my using CallableStatement is wrong.

Comment: where did you set the second parameter ?

Comment: private static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_db";   
private static final String USER = "root";